# Named Shared Memory Issue in C

Tags: c, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I'm writing a program that finds the prime numbers up to 4294967295 (`unsigned int`) using 5 threads. Each thread gets a range of numbers to check using the `IsPrime()` function (I removed the function from the code since it's not where the code breaks), and if the number is prime, it will put the number in a named shared memory file with the size of 500 MB. To make sure the program works, I started with small range of numbers: 0 to 25. So each thread gets 5 numbers to check and to put it in the mapped file. Here's the code:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* The program is using 5 threads to find prime numbers.
therefore, each thread is responsible for finding the numbers
with in a specific range: unsigned int / 5
*/

#define THREAD_1_BEGIN 0
#define THREAD_1_END 5

#define THREAD_2_BEGIN 6
#define THREAD_2_END 10

#define THREAD_3_BEGIN 11
#define THREAD_3_END 15

#define THREAD_4_BEGIN 16
#define THREAD_4_END 20

#define THREAD_5_BEGIN 21
#define THREAD_5_END 25



// The shared variable to hold the total number of primes.
unsigned int totalPrimes = 0;

// Shared memory variables
unsigned char *bitmap;
unsigned int bitmap_size = 4294967295 / 8 + 1; // size of unsigned int
unsigned int *prime_numbers;
unsigned int object_size = 1024 * 1024 * 500; // 500 MB
void *addr;

// Threads
pthread_t threads[5];
pthread_mutex_t total_Mutex;

void *ThreadWorker(void *threadId);
int IsPrime(unsigned int number);
void *mount_shmem(char *path, unsigned int object_size); 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  void *status;

  // Set the threads attributes and mutex
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_mutex_init(&total_Mutex, NULL);

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  // Set the shared memory
  addr = mount_shmem("threadedshm", object_size);
  bitmap = addr;

  prime_numbers = (unsigned int*)(bitmap + bitmap_size);

  for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
    pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, ThreadWorker, (void *)i);
  }

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  // Wait for each thread
  for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
  }

  printf("\n TOTAL: %u \n", totalPrimes);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&total_Mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *ThreadWorker(void *threadId)
{
  int pos = (int) threadId;
  unsigned int t1;
  unsigned int t2;
  unsigned int t3;
  unsigned int t4;
  unsigned int t5;

  if(pos == 0){
    for(t1 = THREAD_1_BEGIN; t1 <= THREAD_1_END; t1++){
      if(IsPrime(t1)){
        printf("Thread 1: %u\n", t1);

        // put it in the shared memory file
        prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t1;

        // Increment the counter by 1
        pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
        totalPrimes++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
      }
    } 
  }else if(pos == 1){
    for(t2 = THREAD_2_BEGIN; t2 <= THREAD_2_END; t2++){
      if(IsPrime(t2)){
        printf("Thread 2: %u\n", t2);

        // put it in the shared memory file
        prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t2;

        // Increment the counter by 1
        pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
        totalPrimes++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
      }
    } 
  }else if(pos == 2){
    for(t3 = THREAD_3_BEGIN; t3 <= THREAD_3_END; t3++){
      if(IsPrime(t3)){
        printf("Thread 3: %u\n", t3);

        // put it in the shared memory file
        prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t3;

        // Increment the counter by 1
        pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
        totalPrimes++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
      }
    } 
  }else if(pos == 3){
    for(t4 = THREAD_4_BEGIN; t4 <= THREAD_4_END; t4++){
      if(IsPrime(t4)){
        printf("Thread 4: %u\n", t4);

        // put it in the shared memory file
        prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t4;

        // Increment the counter by 1
        pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
        totalPrimes++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
        printf("Thread 4: %u\n", t4);

        // put it in the shared memory file
        prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t4;

        // Increment the counter by 1
        pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
        totalPrimes++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
      }
    } 
  }else if(pos == 4){
    for(t5 = THREAD_5_BEGIN; t5 <= THREAD_5_END; t5++){
      if(IsPrime(t5)){
        printf("Thread 5: %u\n", t5);

        // put it in the shared memory file
        prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t5;

        // Increment the counter by 1
        pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
        totalPrimes++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
      }
    } 
  }

  pthread_exit((void*) 0);
}

void *mount_shmem(char *path, unsigned int object_size){
    int shmem_fd;
    void *addr;

    // create and resize the file
    shmem_fd = shm_open(path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (shmem_fd == -1){
        fprintf(stdout, "failed to open shared memory object\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // resize it to 500 MB
    if (ftruncate(shmem_fd, object_size) == -1){
        fprintf(stdout, "failed to resize shared memory object\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     
    }

    addr = mmap(NULL, object_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmem_fd, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED){
        fprintf(stdout, "failed to map shared memory object\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return addr;
}
```

However, at the point of insertion of the number to the array (`prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t1;`) I'm getting a segmentation fault error. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when initiating the shared memory file. I tried it with using only one thread, because I suspected that it might be a mutual exclusion issue where several threads try to update the file at the same time, but it wasn't the issue (I know I'm eventually going to need a mutex or semaphore). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use `#define THREAD_N_BEGIN(x) ((x) * 5)` and `#define THREAD_N_END(x) (THREAD_N_BEGIN(x) + 4)`?  This will make things uniform (at the moment, thread 1 processes 6 numbers and thread 5 processes 4).

Comment: Right but that's not the issue though

Comment: No; it's not the issue that causes your code to fail; that's why I made it into a comment, not an answer.  It does make your code 5 times as big as it need be, and that's why I'm not spending longer looking at it.  There is too much flab and repetition and there might be a subtle flaw (other than the non-uniform distribution of work) in the repeated code, but it is too painful to track any such problem down.

Comment: It just the initial design, the number of threads will be going to be a command-line argument, so I'm going to get rid of the constants anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
prime_numbers = (unsigned int*)(bitmap + bitmap_size);
```

sets `prime_numbers` to point well beyond the extent of the shared memory region pointed to by `bitmap` (this is the cause of your crash).

You also have a race condition, in the code like this:

```
    // put it in the shared memory file
    prime_numbers[totalPrimes] = t1;

    // Increment the counter by 1
    pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
    totalPrimes++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);
```

Since you read `totalPrimes` outside the lock to determine the array index to write to, two threads can write to the same array index, leading to a lost update.  You can fix this by fetching the array index to write to when you perform the increment:

```
    // Increment the counter by 1
    pthread_mutex_lock(&total_Mutex);
    thisPrime = totalPrimes++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&total_Mutex);

    // put it in the shared memory file
    prime_numbers[thisPrime] = t1;
```

Comment: So should it be `prime_numbers = (unsigned int*)(bitmap)` instead? I'm fairly new to the whole pointer arithmetic concept :/

Comment: @programmer93: Yes, that seems likely.

Comment: It worked for 0 to 25. I'm going to try it with 4294967295. Thanks for putting me on the right track :)

Comment: @programmer93: Your `object_size` is not large enough for that, with the code you've shown.  By the way, you don't need to use an explicit shared memory segment, since you are using threads and they share *all* memory.  You could simple allocate a static array.

Comment: Well the point of the assignment is to use shared memory. If not I would simply write it in C# with a nice clean `List<>`. Anyways, how come 500 MB is not large enough?

Comment: @programmer93: It's still shared memory, it's just you don't have to do anything special to make it shared since you're using threads.  Your code stores one 4-byte `unsigned int` in the shared memory segment for each prime, and there are 203,280,221 primes less than or equal to 4,294,967,295.  This means you need 813,120,884 bytes, or a touch over 775MB.

Comment: I have to use an explicit shared memory segment for the assignment :)
Oh I see. 775 MB. That makes sense, how did I miss that? Ok one more thing, when printing out the numbers, they have to be in the correct order. Obviously that's not guaranteed with having several threads. Is there any other way to make this logic happen rather than creating a different mapped file for each thread?

Comment: @programmer93: The simplest way to do so would be to call `qsort()` to sort the shared memory area once all threads have finished.  However, I suspect, based on the name `bitmap` and the calculation of `bitmap_size`, that the intention is for your output data structure to be a set of 4,294,967,295 bits, where the Nth bit is 1 iff N is prime.  If you do this, then printing them in order is natural.